# What are the system sounds for AudioServicesPlaySystemSound?

Tags: ios, ios5, audio, system-sounds

This is just a question that came off of the top of my head, but does anyone know if there are more sounds built into the system besides the (0x450) click sound?  I would assume that there are others that can be put into apps since there are a lot more than just one built into the iPhone.

Comment: See https://github.com/klaas/SwiftySystemSounds a sample app that lets you play all available ones on an iOS device.

Answer (score 20):

There is a list posted to [AudioServices - iPhone Development Wiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices). I've not yet figured out if using this in the following way is grounds for rejection:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1103);
```

Don't forget to include:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

Comment: Please note that this does not work in the simulator! Works fine in the devices.

Answer (score 2):

Check all system sounds with: [iOSSystemSoundsLibrary](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary)